# ext window with bugs on reopening

Tags: extjs

I have a checkbox that triggers a function that opens a small window with a grid and a form.
If `closeAction:'close'` the window is not reopened after closing (some error).
If `closeAction:'hide'` the window is reopened with a mess instead of its items.

I know that I can solve the problem by `id:Ext.id()` though I have other functions that are using the id's. 
Is there a way to reopen the window without these problems?
Part of the function creating the window, nothing unusual:

```
var errWindow = new Ext.Window({
        width:300,
        title:headerStr,
        closeAction:'hide',
        items: [errForm,problemsGrid]
    });
errWindow.show();
```

The items of the form have id's like: "textfieldNumber1". Without the id's everithing works fine, but with them I get this[image]

Comment: ids have to be unique. You may want to use name instead.

Comment: is there a way to access the form fields by name?

Comment: yes. formpanel.getForm().findField(name);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `closeAction: 'close'` which is the default, then the window cannot be reopened with `show()`. If you use use `closeAction: 'hide'` then the window can be shown and hidden but you must do this with `hide()` and `show()` calls. A call to `close()` will destroy the window regardless of what `closeAction` is set to.

Comment: Do I have to destroy all the components one by one? "By default, the close header tool destroys the Window resulting in destruction of any child Components. This makes the Window object, and all its descendants unusable. To enable re-use of a Window, use closeAction: 'hide'." I think I want all the components to be destroyed but the window to be reusable.

Comment: No. Window.close() should destroy all child components. But I thought you didn't want the window destroyed. Which is it?

Comment: Anyway when I click the checkbox the function generates a new window.

Comment: post your code and update the ? with that you actually want then.

Answer (score 1):

Is it that you want to destroy your form when user clicks on close, while keeping window hidden for re-use?

if so,

1. Listen to **beforeClose** event, and remove form from window's items
2. Call windows.hide()

Also, you need to add new form (since you destroyed it), while showing window again. listen to **beforeShow** to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem . As "Narenda Kamma" already mentioned before need to listen to beforeClose and then call to destroy function . See example below

```
var me = this

   this.window.on("beforeclose",
                     function (com, eOpts) { me.closeWindow() });
```